# problem with creating my Context on migration adding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have been working on project for some time now and I was able to add migrations without problem but week or two ago i transitioned from using
 onconfiguring optionsbuilder.useSqlServer to connect to sql server from my context class to using services from Startup class to connect to database

When I try to run add-migration i get this error
Unable to create an object of type 'mojDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Program class

```
 public class Program
{
   
    
    
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

startup class

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

   

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<mojDbContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ererer")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

my context class with removed dbset properties to keep code smaller

```
 public class mojDbContext : DbContext
{
    

   
    public mojDbContext(DbContextOptions<mojDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }



}
```

when i run add-migration -verbose i get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn7Op.png

Comment: Did you update EF? From a certain Version on, you need a parameterless ctor for Migrations. And therefor some kind of fallback-code in OnConfiguring.

Comment: i have target framework set to netcoreapp3.1, didn update anything